# EWS Streaming Subscription with Exchange Online

Tags: streaming, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, subscription, azure-ad-msal

My main question: Working with Exchange Online, how is the streaming subscription supposed to work in relation to the periodic access token refresh?

Details:
I have been using EWS streaming subscriptions for some time for on-premise Exchange.  Following the usual process I create a `StreamingSubscriptionConnection`, add the mailbox subscriptions to it, and then open the connection.  When the `OnDisconnect` event fires, we re-open the connection.

We have now implemented the streaming subscription for mailboxes in Exchange Online, which requires us to use Modern Auth with Microsoft.Identity.Client.  As advised on [this page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/High-availability#pro-active-token-renewal), we are forcing a refresh of the access token every 30 minutes on a background thread.

Everything works great, until we refresh the access token.  At that point, when a connection's `OnDisconnect` event fires, and we attempt to re-open the connection, it fails with 401 Unauthorized.  We currently have it re-assigning the `Credentials` property of the `ExchangeService` object, after refreshing the token, but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the `StreamingSubscriptionConnection` objects which were created prior to refreshing the token.

Note the `StreamingSubscriptionConnection` class doesn't have a `Credentials` property that we can reset after the token refresh.  How is the connection object supposed to get the updated credentials?

Thank you!

John

**UPDATE**

It turns out I was not actually updating the `Credentials` property of the  `ExchangeService` object after refreshing the token.  Once I got that sorted, the re-opening of the connection works fine.

For anyone who might be interested, here's how we're doing this. First define the scopes:

```
private string[] ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/.default" };
```

Now get the access token:

```
_app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_EXOAppId)
        .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, _EXOTenantId)
        .WithClientSecret(_EXOClientSecret)
        .Build();

TokenCacheHelper.EnableSerialization(_app.AppTokenCache);

_EXOAuthResult = await _app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

Then setup a timer to periodically refresh the token (we're doing it every 30 minutes):

```
_nextRefresh = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(refreshInterval);
_refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
_refreshTimer.Interval = 1000;
_refreshTimer.Elapsed += _refreshTimer_Elapsed;
_refreshTimer.Start();
```

And the timer Elapsed event:

```
private async void _refreshTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DateTime.Now < _nextRefresh) return;

    _refreshTimer.Stop();

    _EXOAuthResult = await _app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
        .WithForceRefresh(true) // Do NOT force refresh every time!!
        .ExecuteAsync();

    //--> Here is where you would update the Credentials property of your ExchangeService

    _nextRefresh = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(refreshInterval);
    _refreshTimer.Start();
}
```

That's basically it.  You just need to make sure you're caching the token properly, which should be done by the TokenCacheHelper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was not actually updating the Credentials property of the ExchangeService object after refreshing the token. Once I got that sorted, the re-opening of the connection works fine.